# Convert a path to nodes and edges?

Tags: python, graph, csv

I have a tsv with lots of paths in it :

parts of it looks like this:

```
    14th_century;China;Gunpowder;Fire
    14th_century;Time;Isaac_Newton;Light;Color;Rainbow      
    14th_century;15th_century;16th_century;Pacific_Ocean;Atlantic_Ocean;Accra;Africa;Atlantic_slave_trade;African_slave_trade
```

I want to run trough it and somehow convert it to a something like this:

```
graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
         'B': ['C', 'D'],
         'C': ['D'],
         'D': ['C'],
         'E': ['F'],
         'F': ['C']}
```

Note: That 'A':  is edges and the others os nodes in the path.

at the sametime i want to keep track of how many times each node is visited?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far...

Comment: Nothing really ! i have only counted the numbers of links in the paths . but nothing i could use for this problem

Comment: How do you think you should go about solving the problem?